# Error xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null ); al enviar datos POST en Php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Salduos a todos.

Primero que todo, comento, que casi no sé nada de JavaScript y Ajax, por favor paciencia.

Tengo el siguiente código para insertar datos por Post en php:

```
function editar_aparatos(id) {
            var parametros = {
                "action": "ajax",
                "id": id
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: '../modal/editar/editar_aparatos.php',
                data: parametros,
                beforeSend: function(objeto) {
                    $("#loader3").html("<img src='../../img/ajax-loader.gif'> Cargando...");
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $(".outer_div3").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
                    $("#loader3").html("");
                }
            })
        }
```

Y al analizar el envío me presenta el siguiente error:
xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );

Solo para llegar al error fue una odisea. No tengo ni idea de qué hacer.

Tengo otro código solo cambia la ruta y el objeto y funciona perfecto. (Lo coloco solo para fines de referencia):

```
function editar(id) {
            var parametros = {
                "action": "ajax",
                "id": id
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: '../modal/editar/consulta.php',
                data: parametros,
                beforeSend: function(objeto) {
                    $("#loader2").html("<img src='../../img/ajax-loader.gif'> Cargando...");
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $(".outer_div2").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
                    $("#loader2").html("");
                }
            })
        }
```

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda brindada.

Editado: Código PhP Modal.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_login_status']) and $_SESSION['user_login_status'] != 1) {
    header("location: ../../login.php");
    exit;
}
/* Connect To Database*/
require_once "../../db.php"; //Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
require_once "../../php_conexion.php"; //Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    $id = intval($id);
} else {echo "<script>location.replace('../../consulta.php')</script>";}
?>

<table class="table table-sm" id="productTable4">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:40%;">Estudio Clinico</th>
            <th style="width:50%;">Indicación</th>
            <th style="width:10%;"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php

$orderItemSql    = "SELECT * FROM receta_aparatos WHERE id_consulta = {$id}";
$orderItemResult = $conexion->query($orderItemSql);
 $orderItemData = $orderItemResult->fetch_all();

print_r($orderItemData);
$arrayNumber = 0;
// for($x = 1; $x <= count($orderItemData); $x++) {
$x = 1;
while ($orderItemData = $orderItemResult->fetch_array()) {
     print_r($orderItemData); ?>
    <tr id="row4<?php echo $x; ?>" class="<?php echo $arrayNumber; ?>">
        <td style="margin-left:20px;">
            <div class="form-group">

                <select class="form-control" name="id_aparato[]" id="id_aparato<?php echo $x; ?>" onchange="getProductData(<?php echo $x; ?>)" >
                    <option value="">-- Seleccionar: --</option>
                    <?php
$productSql  = "SELECT * FROM aparatos order by codigo_aparato";
    $productData = $conexion->query($productSql);

    while ($row = $productData->fetch_array()) {
        $selected = "";
        if ($row['id_aparato'] == $orderItemData['aparato_rec']) {
            $selected = "selected";
        } else {
            $selected = "";
        }

        echo "<option value='" . $row['id_aparato'] . "' id='changeProduct" . $row['id_aparato'] . "' " . $selected . " >" . $row['codigo_aparato'] . "</option>";
    } // /while

    ?>
</select>
</div>
</td>
<td style="padding-left:20px;">
    <!-- <div class="form-group"> -->
        <input type="text" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad<?php echo $x; ?>" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $orderItemData['cant_rec']; ?>" />
   <!-- </div> -->
</td>
<td>

    <button class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light removeProductRowBt4" type="button" id="removeProductRowBtn4" onclick="removeProductRow4(<?php echo $x; ?>)"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>
</td>
</tr>
<?php
$arrayNumber++;
    $x++;
} // /for
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="form-group submitButtonFooter" align="center">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success  waves-effect waves-light" onclick="addRowEdit2()" id="addRowBtn4" data-loading-text="Cargando..."> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Añadir fila </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Editado 2: Codigo PhP General (Sentencias MySQL y boton sumit):

```
<?php
include 'is_logged.php'; //Archivo verifica que el usario que intenta acceder a la URL esta logueado
/*Inicia validacion del lado del servidor*/
if (empty($_POST['mod_id_consulta'])) {
    $errors[] = "ID vacío";
} else if (empty($_POST['mod_id_paciente'])) {
    $errors[] = "ID de paciente vacío";
} else if (
    !empty($_POST['mod_id_consulta'])
) {
    /* Connect To Database*/
    require_once "../db.php";
    require_once "../php_conexion.php";
    // escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
    $motivo      = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, (strip_tags($_POST["mod_motivo"], ENT_QUOTES)));
    $fisico      = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, (strip_tags($_POST["mod_fisico"], ENT_QUOTES)));
    $laboratorio = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, (strip_tags($_POST["mod_laboratorio"], ENT_QUOTES)));
    $diagnostico = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, (strip_tags($_POST["mod_diagnostico"], ENT_QUOTES)));
    $peso        = floatval($_POST['mod_peso']);
    $talla       = floatval($_POST['mod_talla']);
    $estatura    = floatval($_POST['mod_estatura']);
    $psa         = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, (strip_tags($_POST["mod_psa"], ENT_QUOTES)));
    //$resumen     = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, (strip_tags($_POST["mod_resumen"], ENT_QUOTES)));
    $fecha_cita  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, (strip_tags($_POST["mod_end"], ENT_QUOTES)));
    $sonda       = intval($_POST['mod_sonda']);
    $fechacol    = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, (strip_tags($_POST["mod_fechacol"], ENT_QUOTES)));
    $cenam       = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, (strip_tags($_POST["mod_cenam"], ENT_QUOTES)));
    $id_consulta = intval($_POST['mod_id_consulta']);
    $id_paciente = intval($_POST['mod_id_paciente']);

    $sql = "UPDATE consulta SET motivo_consul='" . $motivo . "',
                                        examen_fisico_consul='" . $fisico . "',
                                        examen_lab_consul='" . $laboratorio . "',
                                        diagnostico_consul='" . $diagnostico . "',
                                        peso_consul='" . $peso . "',
                                        talla_conul='" . $talla . "',
                                        estatura_consu='" . $estatura . "',
                                        psa_consul='" . $psa . "',
                                        p_cita='" . $fecha_cita . "',
                                        sonda_consulta='" . $sonda . "',
                                        fechacol_consulta='" . $fechacol . "',
                                        cenam_consulta='" . $cenam . "'
                                        WHERE id_consulta='" . $id_consulta . "'";
    $query_update = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

    $readyToUpdateOrderItem = false;
    // add the quantity from the order item to product table
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($_POST['productName']); $x++) {
        //  Tabla de Medicamentos
        $updateProductQuantitySql  = "SELECT medicamentos.stock_medicamento FROM medicamentos WHERE medicamentos.id_medicamento = " . $_POST['productName'][$x] . "";
        $updateProductQuantityData = $conexion->query($updateProductQuantitySql);

        while ($updateProductQuantityResult = $updateProductQuantityData->fetch_row()) {

            if (count($_POST['productName']) == count($_POST['productName'])) {
                $readyToUpdateOrderItem = true;
            }
        } // /for quantity

        // Eeimina todos los Medicamentor relacionados a la consulta
        for ($x = 0; $x < count($_POST['productName']); $x++) {
            $removeOrderSql = "DELETE FROM recetas_medica WHERE id_consulta = {$id_consulta}";
            $conexion->query($removeOrderSql);
        } // /for quantity

        if ($readyToUpdateOrderItem) {
            //insertar los datos del artículo de la receta
            for ($x = 0; $x < count($_POST['productName']); $x++) {
                $updateProductQuantitySql  = "SELECT medicamentos.stock_medicamento FROM medicamentos WHERE medicamentos.id_medicamento = " . $_POST['productName'][$x] . "";
                $updateProductQuantityData = $conexion->query($updateProductQuantitySql);

                while ($updateProductQuantityResult = $updateProductQuantityData->fetch_row()) {
                    $updateQuantity[$x] = $updateProductQuantityResult[0];
                    // Actualiza la cabtidad en la tabla de Medicamentos
                    $updateProductTable = "UPDATE medicamentos SET stock_medicamento = '" . $updateQuantity[$x] . "' WHERE id_medicamento = " . $_POST['productName'][$x] . "";
                    $conexion->query($updateProductTable);
                    // add into order_item

                    $orderItemSql = "INSERT INTO recetas_medica (id_consulta, id_paciente, medicamento_receta, cant_receta, indicacion_receta)
                                    VALUES ('$id_consulta', '$id_paciente', '" . $_POST['productName'][$x] . "','" . $_POST['quantity'][$x] . "','" . $_POST['rate'][$x] . "')";

                    $conexion->query($orderItemSql);
                } // while
            } // /for quantity
        }

        $conexion->close();

    } //for
    // /if $_POST


    // ACTUALIZA LOS APARATOS DE LA CLINICA EN LA BASE DE DATOS

    $ready = false;

    // add the quantity from the order item to product table
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($_POST['id_aparato']); $x++) {
    //  Tabla de aparatos
    $updateCantidad     = "SELECT stock_aparato FROM aparatos WHERE id_aparato = " . $_POST['id_aparato'][$x] . "";
    $updateCantidadData = $conexion->query($updateCantidad);

    while ($updateResult = $updateCantidadData->fetch_row()) {

    if (count($_POST['id_aparato']) == count($_POST['id_aparato'])) {
    $ready = true;
    }
    } // /for quantity

    // Eeimina todos los Medicamentor relacionados a la consulta
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($_POST['id_aparato']); $x++) {
    $removeOrderSql = "DELETE FROM receta_aparatos WHERE id_consulta = {$id_consulta}";
    $conexion->query($removeOrderSql);
    } // /for quantity

    if ($ready) {
    //insertar los datos del artículo de la receta
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($_POST['id_aparato']); $x++) {
    $updateCantidad     = "SELECT stock_aparato FROM aparatos WHERE id_aparato = " . $_POST['id_aparato'][$x] . "";
    $updateCantidadData = $conexion->query($updateCantidad);

    while ($updateResult = $updateCantidadData->fetch_row()) {
   $cantidad[$x] = $updateResult[0];
    // Actualiza la cabtidad en la tabla de Medicamentos
    $updateAparato = "UPDATE aparatos SET stock_aparato = '" . $cantidad[$x] . "' WHERE id_aparato = " . $_POST['id_aparato'][$x] . "";
    $conexion->query($updateAparato);
    // add into order_item 

    $orderItemSql = "INSERT INTO receta_aparatos (id_consulta, id_paciente, aparato_rec, cant_rec)
    VALUES ('$id_consulta', '$id_paciente', '" . $_POST['id_aparato'][$x] . "','" . $_POST['cantidad'][$x] . "')";

    $conexion->query($orderItemSql);
    } // while
    } // /for quantity
    }

    $conexion->close();

    } 

    // /if $_POST






    if ($query_update) {
        $messages[] = "Consulta ha sido actualizada con Exito.";
    } else {
        $errors[] = "Lo siento algo ha salido mal intenta nuevamente.";
    }
} else {
    $errors[] = "Error desconocido.";
}

if (isset($errors)) {

    ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    <strong>Error!</strong>
                    <?php
foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error;
    }
    ?>
            </div>
            <?php
}
if (isset($messages)) {

    ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                        <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
                        <?php
foreach ($messages as $message) {
        echo $message;
    }
    ?>
                </div>
                <?php
}

?>
```

Nota: Error sucede solo con la sección donde // ACTUALIZA LOS APARATOS DE LA CLINICA EN LA BASE DE DATOS.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrarnos el **PHP** al que llamas desde **AJAX**? Parece probable que el problema lo tengas ahí.

Comment: Claro, es un modal.. lo editaré el contenido de mi pregunta.

Comment: ¿Podrías hacerle un `console.log()` a la variable `data` que obtienes en el `success` de la llamada **AJAX** y subirlo? Mirando el **PHP** no veo en primera estancia el problema, vamos a tener que ir acotando para localizarlo.

Comment: Me parece que ese error es devuelto cuando algo anda mal en el servidor. Analizando el código PHP que muestras veo contradicciones: ¿por qué combinas una llamada Ajax con posibles redirecciones desde PHP?. Ajax espera algo del servidor (texto, un json, etc), si desde el PHP rediriges a otra parte ¿qué respuesta va a recibir Ajax? Ajax es una poderosa herramienta y si la usas bien no hay motivo para lógicas tan confusas. Incluso podrías evitar los modales integrando todo en la misma página. Sugiero que hagas una simple prueba, dirigiendo la llamada a un archivo PHP que haga `echo "Test";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si es el único problema, pero esa llamada ajax está haciendo un GET en verdad, si no lo especificas `$.ajax` es GET, si bien en el .php esperas parámetros por GET (`$_GET["id"]`) nunca lo vas a recibir porque los estás poniendo en el `body` del request (`data: parametros`). Puedes o bien enviar un POST (`type: 'post'` en `$.ajax`) y esperar un POST en el php (`$_POST["id"]`) o bien enviar un GET pero pasando los parámetros en la URL, no en el `body`.

Enviando un POST:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
  type: 'post', //<-- Aquí especificas el protocolo
  data: {
    mi_id: 1
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Enviando un GET:

```js
const parametros = {mi_id:1}

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?id='+parametros.mi_id,  
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```